# How to change HTML5 data-attribute value responsively based on screen size

Tags: jquery, media-queries, custom-data-attribute

i'm using [an Instagram widget](http://stadget.com) to show pics on website.

it uses jquery and works fine, but i think i've hit a limitation with it.

i've got it displaying 2 columns and showing 12 images total. it does this by using "data-attributes" inside a "div" tag. here's an example...

```
<div class="instawidget" data-amount="12" data-grid="2"></div>
```

this works fine for tablet & desktop screens, but not mobile (given my particular layout).

so, for smaller screens, i'm trying to change the "data-amount" value from 12 to 6.

i have learned that unfortunately, CSS cannot alter this kind of HTML. so i thought i could just duplicate the div, having one for the 12 & one for the 6, then use CSS Media Queries to show/hide the appropriate div based on min/max-width, like this...

```
CSS...
@media screen and (min-width: 736px) {
    div.instawidget[data-amount="12"] {
        display: block;
    }
    div.instawidget[data-amount="6"] {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
    div.instawidget[data-amount="6"] {
        display: block;
    }
    div.instawidget[data-amount="12"] {
        display: none;
    }
}

HTML...
<div class="instawidget" data-amount="12" data-grid="2"></div>
<div class="instawidget" data-amount="6" data-grid="2"></div>
```

now, the actual display of each div DOES work - but it doesn't matter, because what does NOT work is, the "data-amount" value of whichever div is on top is the one that sticks.

in other words, if it's as i have above, then both large & small screens will show 12 images. and if i switch it & reverse the order, then both screen sizes will show 6 images.

i've been searching a lot & cannot find that this is necessarily the behavior of html5 data attributes, but i don't know for sure.

so if it isn't, then what am i doing wrong with my css?

if it is, then is there a reasonable cross-browser solution?

i've found a few Jquery & Javascript offerings in other stacks, but i don't know enough about programming those to make them work in this situation. i can usually fudge it enough to get them to work but all the examples were too varied or general for me to see enough patterns to copy.

note: whatever solution ya'll can help me with, i would prefer for the page to NOT have to refresh/reload when the browser window is resized across the breakpoints. ideally, the data-amount would just change & the number of images on the page would just change.

thanks for the help.

Comment: If you alter the `data-amount` attribute within the inspector, does it immediately change the rendered layout? Or is it being built on page load? If it's the former, you can easily alter the data attribute based on page width using Javascript.

Comment: no, altering the data-amount in chrome dev inspector does NOT change it on the page (i expected it would/should, so not sure why it doesn't). i thought finding a JS solution was how i was going to have to deal with this, but your "nth-child" css solution below works very well for this situation. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but I believe you're just trying to show only 6 images on mobile instead of 12. If that's the case, you can easily accomplish this with CSS without needing to duplicate the widget:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .instawidget li:nth-child(n+7) {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="instawidget" data-user-name="kevin" data-amount="12" data-grid="2"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="//www.stadget.com/cdn/widget-init.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh YES! PERFECT! THANK YOU SO MUCH! i was hoping for a short'n'simple solution and this is just that. i really appreciate it. you nailed it. ✌